# My symbolic polynomial it's not a symbolic polynomial?! Weird error

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, polynomial-math, coefficients

I have an symbolic expression like this:

`syms h`

`g=exp(h)+h*exp(h)+h^2*exp(h);`

And I really need to extract an polynomial from it, so I wrote:

`polyn=coeffs(g,exp(h))`

which gives me an symbolic polynomial in `h` equal to: `h^2+h+1`.

Now, I want to extract the coefficients from this symbolic polynomial:

`coeff=sym2poly(polyn);`

But I'm getting the error message:

"**Error using symengine (line 58)
Expression is not a polynomial.**"

So, either has a bug in my computer (which there's a chance to) or Matlab is not recognizing my "symbolic polynomial" as an symb. polyn, actually.

I have to mention that if I type:

`polyn=h^2+h+1;`

`coeff=sym2poly(polyn);`

I dont get any error at all! However, since I am programming, I cant type this polynomial, so I need to obtain it in the way I did.

Is there something I can do here??

Comment: I followed your code and I got no error. Are you sure your code doesn't do anything with `polyn` between `coeffs` and `sym2poly`? Maybe you could add a breakpoint right before `sym2poly` and see what `polyn` looks like.

Comment: @erfan gonna test this tomorrow in a decent computer, I dont trust mine. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that works for me:

```
syms h
g= exp(h)+h*exp(h)+h^2*exp(h);
polyn= coeffs(g,exp(h))
polyn= sym(char(polyn));
coeff= sym2poly(polyn)
```